# Maya Python: Change selected menuItem in an optionMenu

Tags: python, user-interface, maya, optionmenu

I am trying to figure out how to change the menuItem selection in an optionMenu but am unable to figure it out.

```
mymenu = cmds.optionMenu(label ='select type', cc=selectTypeCallback)
cmds.menuItem(parent=mymenu, label='selection1')
cmds.menuItem(parent=mymenu, label='selection2')
```

Now how do I call call mymenu again and check the current selected menuItem to the one i choose?

Answer (score 2):

I've worte you a full working example with some good practise, your answer are the four last lines :)

```
    from functools import partial

    # Something to parse ui element, it is important to make difference between ui query and functions
    def optionMenuParser_string(opM_name, func, *args):
        # *args (or could be **kwargs) is here to pass maybe more arguments to a function
        string = cmds.optionMenu(opM_name, q=True, v=True) # you could even parse some flag or anything
        if args and len(args) > 1:
            # args len must be superior to 1 because maya always input True argument
            func(string, *args)
        else:
            func(string)

    # A function doing something with the string
    def printNewMenuItem( item ):
        print item 

    window = cmds.window()
    cmds.columnLayout()
    # change command='' is a placeholder to input back the option menu name
    mygroup = cmds.optionMenu( label='Colors', changeCommand='' )
    # partial is used to put arguments in a function trhought the ui
    cmds.optionMenu(mygroup, e=1, changeCommand= partial(optionMenuParser_string, mygroup, printNewMenuItem) )
    cmds.menuItem( p=mygroup, label='Yellow' )
    cmds.menuItem( p=mygroup, label='Purple' )
    cmds.menuItem( p=mygroup, label='Orange' )
    cmds.showWindow( window )


    cmds.optionMenu(mygroup, q=True, v=True) # to get the name of the current value
    cmds.optionMenu(mygroup, q=True, sl=True) # to get the current index
    cmds.optionMenu(mygroup, e=True, sl = 3 )# to change the current value
    cmds.optionMenu(mygroup, e=True, v = 'Purple' )# to change the current value
```